# Remove space below footer?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to remove the white space below the footer in :- http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/

I've fixed this by adding {position:fixed;width:100%} but it only works for a few pages. For the other pages the footer doesn't appear at all. I've also read this but it doesn't seem to work : [Can't remove Whitespace at the bottom of my document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557974/cant-remove-whitespace-at-the-bottom-of-my-document).

Could someone please explain what is the error here?

Comment: Your link works for me in Chrome, what browser/version are you using?

Comment: chrome version 31.0 linux version

Comment: If you change the color of the footer, there should be some white space or background behind it.

Comment: Sorry but the link works for me in Chrome 33, IE8-11, and the latest Safari and Firefox on Windows. The footer sits at the bottom of the screen until it is brought up to meet with the content at which point it remains below the content and a scrollbar is shown. I assume this is the expected behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, I'm thinking this is a browser or extension issue.

Answer (score 0):

I once had the same issue using bootstrap
I used this css to stick the footer to the bottom of the page:

```
    *{
     margin: 0;
     }

     .wrapper{
     min-height: 100%;
     height: auto !important;
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0 auto -0em;
     }

     .footer, .push{
     height: 2em;
     }

     .footer, .push{
     clear: both;
     }
```

Put all the content in the wrapper class and use the footer class below the wrapper.
I found it somewhere when I had this issue and it worked.

Comment: Could you go to the first link that I provided and see if there is space under the footer there? And also let me know your browser version.

Comment: I don't see any space. Using Google Chrome version 31.0.1650.63 m

Comment: Thanks, I think this has to do with one of my extension scripts.