# Spacing generating from script tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have eight scripts on the body of the html such as, 
they take some space. I tried to remove this by adding a div and inside the div I put disply:none. it didn't work then as for the following link 
http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?336853-weird-spacing-issue-from-script-tag
I changed it to margin-top : -12px it didn't work. after that i changed -12 -84 since I had 8 script that also didn't change a thing. my div is like this now.

```
.hiddenScript{
margin-top : -1000px;
margin-bottom : -1000px;
padding-top:  -1000px;

height: -1000px;
}
```

All of these steps didn't change a thing. Please let me know what i'm doing wrong. thanx in advance.

Comment: My guess it's the spacing around a script. If this tag isn't in the <head> then the newlines before and after it might affect the layout. (you probably removed the whole line when removing the script tag)

Comment: no when i remove the script tags the empty spaces goes away

Comment: got the answer from a previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557974/cant-remove-whitespace-at-the-bottom-of-my-document